# Show that a problem is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques, correctness-proof, proof-assistants

The problem is, K_longestPath:

> We are given a graph in which some of the vertices are "cities". No two cities have an edge between them, thus every city must be at distance at least 2 from each other city. We have to find a path that goes through each such city without forming a cycle.

We are given the Graph with a valid configuration of cities and we have to find if there exists such a path.

At first I was thinking solving this with Hamiltonian path, but to show that the problem is NP-complete I have to find an algorithm that will change it's inputs to be inputs for this problem that we got, and I don't know how to do this..

Comment: I get the gist of your question, but your definition of "city" isn't quite right. The input graph has vertices, and some of those vertices are cities, and we are told which ones, right? If so, 'We are given a graph in which some of the vertices are "cities". No two cities have an edge between them, thus every city must be at distance at least 2 from each other city' is clearer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker i'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose an NP-hard problem, and show a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm that transforms any instance of this NP-hard problem to an instance of your city problem that is true if and only if the original instance was true. As you suggested in the question, *Hamiltonian path* is a good choice for the starting problem.

Try to create an algorithm that takes any Hamiltonian path instance and constructs a "city problem" instance which has the same truth value. You must also write a **proof** that, for any input instance of Hamiltonian path, the corresponding output instance of the "city problem" has the same truth value.

Hint 1:

> Think about [subdividing edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing).

Hint 2:

> If you take an arbitrary (undirected simple) graph and subdivide each edge once, you get a graph in which none of the original vertices are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Yes, that's right; but to prove that my problem is NP-complete I need to solve another known Np-complete problem and transform the inputs from my problem tu the inputs of thst problem using some deterministic polynomial algorithm, isnt that right? isnt that what I have to do?

Comment: @CCristi See my latest edit, and read the wording very carefully.

Comment: ohhhh, okay, so I have to write an algorithm which generates a valid city-graph, and then feed it to the Hamiltonian path problem? am I on the right track? and if I am, say I have the algorithm that generates a valid city-graph, how should I write the proof..? Where should I start?

Comment: No, you have to find an algorithm $M$ which expects an instance $w$ of $HP$ and returns an instance of  $LP$. Formally, for that algorithm it must hold that $w \in HP$ then $M(w) \in LP$ and  $w \not \in HP$ then $M(w) \not \in LP$

Comment: You should look at reduction proofs, understand what they do and then you can apply that knowledge to your problem.

Comment: For the sake of completeness (pun not intended), I would add that you also have to show that your problem is in NP. This only shows it is NP-hard but says nothing about NP-completeness.

Comment: @Ordoshsen and how do I show that they have the same truth value?

Comment: okay, we're given a graph which we can apply HP to it, we mark every node as a city then we divide each edge in 2 edges to make it valid, thus we can still apply HP to it and the value of truth must remain. Is that right?

Comment: @Ordoshsen am I correct?

Comment: What I said is actually different problem. You need to treat the new instance you created as an instance of your problem, not HP, then I believe your comment to be correct. This proves that your problem is NP-hard. Now you have to show that it is also NP to prove it is NP-complete. The easiest way is with a certificate

Comment: @Ordoshsen what do you mean a certificate? Yes, they will be an instance of my problem, but what I am saying is that if the given problem was an instance of the HP problem and then I transformed that into an instance of my problem, if the instance of the HP problem had the result of 1 then this means that also the instance of my problem must have a result of 1, right?

Comment: @C.Cristi yes, that should be correct. Sorry, but you have to do your own research on the other part of the problem. Just look for a way to prove a problem is in NP, on definition of NP and certificate definition of NP.